# Looking for a python .split() type function that casts as a float

Tags: python

```
 if bool(re.search(r'\d', oz)) == 1:
        pounds, ounces = oz.split(':')
        pounds = float(pounds)
        ounces = float(ounces)  
        pounds = pounds * 16
        oz = pounds + ounces
        oz = float(oz)
        print(oz)
    else:
        print("You must enter a digit\n")
        main()
```

So, when I use split to split user input in to lb and oz, the input becomes a string. Is there any sort of splitting function that works with integers and floats? This way of doing it seems a little shady. What is a cleaner, more elegant way of handling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pounds, ounces = map(float, oz.split(':'))
```

`map` actually apply a function on the iterable specified which in this case is `oz.split(':')`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `list-comprehension`:

```
pounds, ounces = [float(i) for i in oz.split(':')]
```

It is the same efficiency as your code, but just looks a lot neat and I find it cleaner personally. It would also be *more* scalable if for some reason there would be more `:`s in the `oz` string (I say *more* as the `unpacking` would need modification).

---

As a side note, you could cram that whole part of your `code` into a  `one-liner` which would be very neat with `sum` on a `generator` if you didn't have to multiply the `pounds` by `16`. That isn't to say it isn't possible (below) but its up to you what you prefer!

```
oz = float(a[:a.index(":")]) + float(a[a.index(":")+1:]) * 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. At least the converting to float is fine. There are a bunch of issues that are unrelated - you assume the string is a `number:number`, you call ounces pounds (`pounds = pounds * 16` these are no longer pounds) and such.

The conversion to float, as ever, is fine.

Comment: Agree with your assessment. I plan to clean it up. This was part of cleaning it up, as it is rough right now. :)